# backbone.js pass parameters between backbone pages without query string

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-routing

Im currently on the index page, and on click of a button i need to have if an else statement, on which if the if is true i need to open new backbone page and pass the parameters from current page to the new backbone page.  I've the new page, and i set up my routes, and im able to visit the new page.  Im using the following

```
Backbone.history.navigate('newPage', {trigger: true});
```

how do i pass parameters to this new page, for example i need to pass title of a product.  how do i pass it without the query string.  Suppose there are multiple products on the current page, if i click on any one product on current page, the new page should have that info.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: But why not use the query string, so that the page is bookmarkable?  That's the whole point of calling `navigate`, isn't it?

Comment: i'm new to backbone. i was reading the documentation and other links.  it seemed like navigate is a good method to navigate from one page to another.  So i'm trying to use it.  Is there any better way?

Comment: I'm just saying, if you're not going to update the URL (by using the query string), then what is the point in using the Router at all?  Just render the new content as needed.  But also, why averse to using the query string?  Seems like that would be best.